# Express $f(x) = x^2 \cos(2x) + \sin^2(x)$ as a power series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Express $f(x) = x^2 \cos(2x) + \sin^2(x)$ as a power series

What I know:

> I know that $$x^2\cos(2x) = x^2 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \cdot \frac{(2x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^n \cdot \frac{2^{2n} \cdot x^{2n+2}}{(2n)!}}$$

But how do we find what $\sin^2(x)$ is in terms of a power series?

Comment: Well, you could square the standard power series for $\sin$, or you could use $\sin^2(x)=(1-\cos(2x))/2$.

Comment: To check your answer, c.f. the second page of these notes: http://orion.math.iastate.edu/vika/cal3_files/Lec27.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### HINT

$$ \sin^2 {x} = 1 - \cos^2 {x} = \dfrac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \theta$.

Answer (score 0):

**One more hint:**

Take the term by term derivative, and use: $$\sin x = -\frac{d\cos x}{ dx}$$